# split string from start - to end like object

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

```js
var string = 'job_category=IT^job_description=<p><span style="font-size: 18px;">Many other html attribute's </span></p>^job_type=2^qualification=2^EQ';

//oneline string to object starts here
function get_json_from_string(x) {
 var ob = {};
 var a = x.split("^");
 for( i = 0 ;  i < a.length ; i++){
  var t = a[i].split('=');
  ob[ t[0] ] = t[1];
 }
 return ob;
}
//oneline string to object ends here


var finalOutput = get_json_from_string(string); 
console.log(finalOutput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want the HTML the whole job_description from the string but when i use split its is breaking upto = double quotation.

how can I split correctly?

expected results key value of object:

```
job_description:"<p><span style="font-size: 18px;">Many other html attributes </span></p>"
```

current result  key value of object:

```
job_description:"<p><span style="
//font-size: 18px;">Many other html attributes </span></p>   this is cropping
```

> Note Plese check my string carefully it can contain single and double quotations

Comment: Your code doesn't run.  It looks like the string just needs to be wrapped in quotes correctly.

Comment: I can't do that because the data in job_description may also contain single quotation , so if i use it will break up to there –i need any strong solution

Comment: Where exactly is `string` coming from?  I'm assuming it's not a static variable in your javascript and you are just showing us an example value.

Comment: How do you get the string value?  When you get it I have to assume it's valid JSON, so you *should* be able to simply wrap it in relevant quotes and it *will* work in code.

Comment: the string what i displayed that how I get, it's not in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on the '^' and then split on the '=', taking the first element as the key, and then joining the rest back up by '=' for the value.

```js
var string = `job_category=IT^job_description=<p><span style="font-size: 18px;">Many other html attribute's </span></p>^job_type=2^qualification=2^EQ`;

//oneline string to object starts here
function get_json_from_string(x) {
  return x.split('^').reduce(function(result, token){
    var subtokens = token.split('=');
    result[subtokens[0]] = subtokens.slice(1).join('=');
    return result;
  }, {});
}
//oneline string to object ends here


var finalOutput = get_json_from_string(string); 
console.log(finalOutput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Advance level of coding.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna wanna look for the first `=` only and ignore any following `=`s.

```js
var string = 'job_category=IT^job_description=<p><span style="font-size: 18px;">Many other html attributes </span></p>^job_type=2^qualification=2^EQ'

//oneline string to object starts here
function get_json_from_string(x) {
 var ob = {};
 var a = x.split("^");
 for( i = 0 ;  i < a.length ; i++){
  var eq = a[i].indexOf('=')
  if(eq==-1){
   //no = in this part... handle it yourself
   continue;
  }
  var key = a[i].slice(0,eq)
  var value = a[i].slice(eq+1)
  ob[ key ] = value;
 }
 return ob;
}
//oneline string to object ends here


var finalOutput = get_json_from_string(string); 
console.log(finalOutput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solution is missing the ending key without a value `EQ`

Comment: as stated in the comment at `if(eq==-1)`, try handling it yourself. just make `key=a[i]` and set the value to whatever you like.

Answer (score -1):

In your JSON object in value `"<p><span style="font-size: 18px;">Many other html attributes </span></p>"` use single quotes (...style='font-size:18px;'...) instead of double quotes.

Comment: I can't do that because the data in job description may contain single quotaion tooo so it will break upto there

Comment: What about escaping inner double quotes? (eg: ...style=\"font-size:18px;\"...)